# Custom SoundCloud API library upload error with PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, soundcloud

For various reasons I'm writing my own SoundCloud API library and I ran into a problem with uploading a sound file.

For the task I'm using PHP and Curl, but SoundCloud doesn't want to accept my file when using PHP. When I tried it from the terminal, it worked fine and the file was uploaded successfully. I used the following command in terminal:

```
curl -i -X POST "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks" -F 'oauth_token=asdasdasdasd' -F 'track[asset_data]=@/home/.../www_data/upload/mpthreetest.mp3' -F 'track[title]=test'
```

After this I tried PHP Curl but I git the following error: `Couldn't upload that sound. Couldn't upload that file, sure they're valid soundfiles?`. I tried an `.mp3` and a `.wav` file as well.

This is my PHP code:

```
$url = "{$this->apiURL}/tracks";

$curl = curl_init();
// Set options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
        'oauth_token' => $this->getToken(),
        'track[asset_data]' => '@/home/.../upload/mpthreetest.mp3',
        'track[title]' => 'test'))
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($resp);

curl_close($curl);
```

I tried removing the `@` from the beginning of the path, but didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you just said, the `http_build_query` is what messes up the query.

The reason for this is that the previously mentioned function converts every special character to http conform characters. This means the `@` becomes `%40` and `/` becomes `%20`.

As it seems, cURL does not recognise afterwards that the given string is actually a path. Out of this, it sends plain text. Which means that the target api is not receiving a binary file, but the path the file is located at instead.

If encoding is necessary, I would separate the file option from the others, encode them, and append it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite disturbing.

The http_build_query() was the culprit. Leaving that out solves the problem and the upload succeeds.